# vs code debugging has the wrong line numbers

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a source file that starts with PHP, then html and JavaScript.
When is debug the program, the Chrome developer tools does not show the PHP code. It only shows  html and JavaScript.
If I place a break point in the developer tools, the program breaks at that location. vs code shows it stopping 20 lines sooner. The php portion of the program is 122 lines.
If I place a breakpoint in vs code, then the dev tools stop at the wrong location.
How do I correct this?

Comment: Of course the Chrome developer tools does not show the PHP code. That is not available in the client (the browser). It was run on the server and the output was sent to the client.

Comment: The best you can do is probably to move the JavaScript to a separate file which you load into the page using `<script src="the_script.js"></script>`. Then the file that the browser gets will be equal to the one you have in VSCode and the line numbers will match.

Comment: I was thinking moving the code may help. I will  give it a try.